# InternalServerError when I use Azure function to get Metadata in Azure data factory

Tags: c#, https, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have referred this article
https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_more_metadata
follow the try it out steps to build the solution and deploy to the Azure function
but when I use data factory to call the function and use

[image]

will get the fail message

[image]

mystorageaccount is testdemo0428 container is test2 and I want to know the things in f2

I just wanted to know if this problem is from the Azure side or due to the code which the article provide. Any help would be appreciated. Also if is a code problem please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario in my environment and got same error in ADF.

[image]

Here, the above error in ADF arise when there is a compilation error in the function code. I got it due to same.

[image]

So, the issue is from the Azure functions code side and not from ADF.
Recheck your Azure functions code if it has any errors.

[image]

Instead of calling directly from ADF, first check your code by running it manually with the same body and make the necessary changes as the above sample.